# Remove bibliography header from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

How can I remove the bibliography from table of contents?

I'm using this code :

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

%content content content %

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  this is usually dependent on the document class you are using, but you haven't said which one that is.

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}` memoir :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the O.P. stated he uses `memoir` as document class, so this is a possible (and most likely the easiest) solution:

Use the `\nobibintoc` command to prevent the inclusion of the bibliography in the ToC -- by default (see the relevant code at the end of this answer) `\bibintoc` is effective and enables the inclusion.

And here is the solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\nobibintoc
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{And now for something completely different}

\cite{Lam94}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}

%\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Only for interested readers**

Here's the relevant portion of `memoir.cls` which shows that inclusion of `bibliography` in the ToC is the default.

```
...
\newcommand{\@memb@bchap}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}%
  \bibmark
  \ifnobibintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \fi
  \prebibhook}
\newcommand{\@memb@bsec}{\section{\bibname}\prebibhook}
\newcommand{\bibsection}{\@memb@bchap}

\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \bibsection
  \begin{bibitemlist}{#1}}{\end{bibitemlist}\postbibhook}
\newif\ifnobibintoc
\newcommand*{\bibintoc}{\nobibintocfalse}
\newcommand*{\nobibintoc}{\nobibintoctrue}
\bibintoc
...
```

Comment: Adding the code of the command just confuses this answer, IMO. Showing how to do it for the standard classes too might be more helpful.

Comment: @AlanMunn: In standard classes there is no automatic addition of `bibliography` -- what should I show there then?  Whatever I do there will be complains :-(

Comment: Oops, you're right, I forgot the standard classes do it oppositely. But I still think you make things more complicated by adding the code.  And there's another simple way to do this without `\nobibintoc`: `\addcontentsline{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}` just before the `\bibliography` command. (Not needed for `memoir` but the simple way to exclude things usually I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Do you really think that `\addtocontents{...}{...}` (!!!!) is easier than `\nobibintoc` for a (perhaps) not so experienced user, apart from eventually reversing it afterwards (depending on user's request)? ;-)

Comment: No of course, not. And I didn't say that. But the memoir code fragment doesn't enlighten us on how to do it more generally, that's all, and this code fragment would.

Comment: thanks a lot @ChristianHupfer for the part "Only for interested readers" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345573/141273)'s simple and direct answer: make the command `\addtocontents` temporarily do nothing, add the bibliography, and then recover the command `\addtocontents` if it is required after the bibliography.

Comment: This is a legit answer; short but informative.