# Remove bibliography part in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning, revtex, journal-publishing

I use the following code to generate a paper with its supplemental material. I only want a table of contents for the supplementary part. However, as you see, the table of contents lists the *References* of the paper main text part as well. How can we avoid this? Thanks.
[image]

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{my name}
\affiliation{Somewhere}

\begin{abstract}
my abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\textit{Introduction.---}%
We have many things to say\cite{Giuliani2005SM}.

\begin{thebibliography}{95}%
    \bibitem{Giuliani2005SM} 
    G.F. Giuliani and G. Vignale, 
    \textit{Quantum theory of the electron liquid} (Cambridge University Press, 2005).
\end{thebibliography}%


%Start Supplemental Material

%%%%%%%%%% Merge with supplemental materials %%%%%%%%%%
%\newpage
\onecolumngrid
%\newpage
{
    \center \bf \large 
    Supplemental Material\vspace*{0.1cm}\\ 
    \vspace*{0.0cm}
}
\twocolumngrid  

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{App:section}
haha\cite{Hanamura1970SM}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{Hanamura1970SM} E. Hanamura, J. Phys. Soc. Jpn. {\bf 29}, 50 (1970).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To avoid `thebibliography` from setting a section-like entry in the ToC, wrap the following around it:

```
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline% Store \addcontentsline
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Make \addcontentsline a no-op
\begin{thebibliography}{X}%
  % <bibitems>
\end{thebibliography}%
\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline% Restore \addcontentsline
```

The above sequence stores `\addcontentsline` and then redefines it to do nothing. This way nothing gets written to the ToC as part of the `thebibliography` environment. Finally, we restore `\addcontentsline` after the environment.

[image]